# Get Data Error By WMI Class Win32_OperatingSystem

Tags: wmi

Here is a sample at [CSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa390423%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

But if I want to get an uint64 value(such as TotalVirtualMemorySize in Win32_OperatingSystem)
The code below:

```
hr = pclsObj->Get(L"TotalVirtualMemorySize ", 0, &vtProp, 0, 0);
wcout << " OS Name : " << vtProp.ullVal<< endl;
```

Will not worked!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `uintVal` field instead

```
wcout << "TotalVirtualMemorySize : " << vtProp.uintVal << endl;
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.I had tried uintVal, but it did not worked too!

Comment: Anyway is you have any doubt, you can use this tool `WMI Delphi Code Creator` http://code.google.com/p/wmi-delphi-code-creator/

Comment: I have tried WMI delphi Code Creator, but the result is not correct too!

Comment: And the C# code is RIGHT, but the C++ code result is ERROR. amazing！

Comment: finally, I got the answer from here:http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vclanguage/thread/cd62e208-69a1-4514-b0d6-071fcabae0fe   I use :wcout << _wtoi64(vtProp.bstrVal) / 1000 / 1000 / 1000 << endl;